# Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 32 categories

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to run random forest with a set of data that is 1664 (columns) x 208 (rows). My dependent variable is retention time (seconds), and my independent variables are 1664 different descriptors all the different chemical compounds. All of the descriptors give a value and are not categorical variables. I'm trying to perform a random forest for regression. However, when I try to run it using the following code:-

```
urine.rf <- randomForest(RT..seconds.~., data=urine, importance=TRUE)
```

I get the message:-

Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 32 categories.

I read online that you can get around this by constructing some form of model.matrix. I'm completely new to R and haven't got the faintest clue about how to do this. I've tried formatting my cells in my csv file so that all the cells were numbers, but for some reason it still comes across as categorical predictors. How do I get around this?

```
RT (seconds)    1_MW    2_AMW   3_Sv    4_Se    5_Sp    6_Ss    
46.58353    155.18  7.76    11.8    20.61   12.21   32.67   0.59
46.79514    145.29  5.01    14.76   28.37   16.11   21  0.51
48.18893    169.21  7.36    13.4    23.49   13.97   34.17   0.58
49.94328    169.21  7.36    13.4    23.49   13.97   34.17   0.58
50.81087    187.33  5.51    17.87   33.59   19.32   30.17   0.53
51.3834 104.2   4.96    10.39   20.67   11.41   16.5    0.49
51.51799    125.17  8.94    7.41    14.81   8.3 27.92   0.53
52.67208    117.13  7.81    8.2 15.73   8.45    29.33   0.55
52.79043    137.18  7.22    11.59   19.12   12.13   26.33   0.61
52.79046    161.23  6.2 13.71   26.27   14.7    33.5    0.53
```

This is what the database I'm using looks like. I want RT to be my Y variable, and everything else (1_MW and all the others after) to be my independent variables (there's 1664)

Thanks

Comment: What is `table(apply(urine, 2, class))`?

Comment: (Also, that is a ludicrously large number of predictors for just 208 rows but that's another question!)

Comment: I applied that code and got:- character 1661
So I'm guessing it's not registering my data as numerical values?

Comment: Yeah I know it's a large number of predictors, it's all about trying to determine what physio-chemical properties of metabolites are most important in determining retention time, and there's a lot of different properties to take into consideration haha

Comment: Yeah, that's saying you've got 1661 character vectors. How did you import this data (did you use `read.csv`)? It's possible you've chosen a funny `header` setting that means it's interpreting your headers as data, or you've got a row of data that includes non-numbers. Is `names(urine)[1:3]` equal to `[1] RT (seconds)  1_MW  2_AMW`?

Comment: I just tried `names(urine)[1:3]` and it does equal the column names. I did use `read.csv`. I did it with another database that contained the exact same number of predictor variables, did the same method and it worked fine, it just doesn't seem to work in this database. I scanned through it and couldn't find anything that isn't a non-number except for some 'NULL' values, however that was also present in the other database that worked.

Comment: I've just replaced all NULL values in the database with 0s and performed it and it works fine. Thank you! You helped me figure it out.

Comment: Aha! Explicit `'NULL'`s are interpreted as characters. You should use `urine <- read.csv("filename.csv", na.strings=c("", "NA", "NULL"))`

Comment: Check out the xgboost package which uses a matrix transformation of the data for prediction, turning each factor category into its own binary predictor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to complete this. I had the exact same problems, and it took me 10 minutes to figure out that there were hidden comments. Thus:

**the solution may be in that the null values are interpreted as characters**

Try to use the na.strings option:

```
read.csv("filename.csv", na.strings=c("", "NA", "NULL"))
```

Comment: Now I am getting error   `Error in na.fail.default(data(dependent_variable = c(36L, 57L, 74L, 74L,  : missing values in object`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that one-hot encoding using model.matrix may create really sparse datasets.

Another option is to actually use a recent packages that are purpose-built for highly dimensional / high volume data sets. They run their code using lower-level languages (C++ and/or Java) and in certain cases use parallelization for faster processing.

I'd recommend taking a look into these three:

ranger (uses C++ compiler) randomForestSRC (uses C++ compiler) h2o (Java compiler - needs Java version 8 or higher) Also, some additional reading here to give you more to go off on which package to choose: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04409.pdf

Page 8 shows benchmarks showing the performance improvement of ranger against randomForest against growing data size - ranger is WAY faster due to linear growth in runtime rather than non-linear for randomForest for rising tree/sample/split/feature sizes.

Beyond that, using variable importance to reduce the feature size to those with the most information would improve model performance/accuracy.

Good Luck!